# Polymer elements aren't responsive

Tags: css, web, polymer

I'm trying to build a responsive website with polymer, but for some reason some elements (core-toolbar and paper-fab) don't get scaled on a smaller and more dense screen (see smartphones). From the project I've seen online (IE: https://www.polymer-project.org, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZAc51_0Xa_M) it seems like I'm the only one having this problem, so I think I'm missing something.

Here's my code along with two screenshots, one from my smartphone, the other one from my PC.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
    <!--<link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-scaffold/core-scaffold.html">-->
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-fab/paper-fab.html">

    <style>
    body {
        font-family: Roboto;
    }

    core-toolbar {
        background-color: #03b7d3;
        color: white;
    }

    .mainFab {
        z-index:100;
        background-color: #ff5c9d;
        /*position: absolute;*/
        top: 70px;
        right: 16px;*/
    }

    </style>

</head>

<body fullbleed layout vertical>
    <core-header-panel flex>
        <core-toolbar class="medium-tall" core-narrow>
            <div>Gabriele Musco</div>
            <span flex></span>
            <paper-fab icon="toc" class="mainFab"></paper-fab>
        </core-toolbar>
        <!--content goes here-->

    </core-header-panel>


</body>
```

[image: PC Screenshot]

[image: Smartphone Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Just solved this adding these two lines in the head of my html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
```